# Authenticate to STS by Issued Token

Tags: wcf, wif, ws-federation, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm working on federating an application with various areas and extremely fine-grained permissions. Each of the various areas has a federated WCF endpoint to communicate back to the server. Because of the fine grained permissions, a single token containing all of the permissions can be as large as 1MB, maybe more.

Requirements dictate that the user's username and password credentials must not be held within our code base after the initial log in process. The permissions cannot be combined to create a smaller set. We are using the Thinktecture.IdentityServer for our STS implementation.

My proposed solution is to break each endpoint into its own realm in the STS, and the STS will return a token with the permission claims specified for the realm. To accomplish this I would like to have an Auth realm which is authenticated by username/password and returns a token containing a user, tenant, and subgroup IDs which could then be used as credentials for authenticating to other realms.

Setting up the STS to issue tokens specific to realms has already been implemented. The only requirement remaining is that the username/password is not kept around within our code base.

Is it possible to configure the STS to allow authentication by providing a previously issued token from a specific realm? Is there a better solution which I have not come upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can authenticate to STS A using a token issued by STS B. STS A has to be configured to trust STS B as a known identity provider.

With thinktecture STS I think you can do this by configuring a new WSStar identity provider. If one realm STS adds the other realm STS as an identity provider, it should begin accepting tokens issued from that realm+certificate.

For WCF, a reasonably painless way to set up issued token channels is with the WIF CreateChannelWithIssuedToken extension method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517268.aspx

1MB is a very big token indeed. There may be other good reasons to split into multiple STSes in separate realms, but you might alternatively help to solve the problem by dynamically deriving permissions through a policy or permissions stores on the relying party side where your token gets consumed rather than pre-calculating all the granular permissions from the STS side. But I say this without knowing your specific application so feel free to tell me to go away :)

Comment: I'm assuming this will work as well if STS A === STS B and will try this. I will mark this as the accepted answer if it works. Regarding using a permissions store on the RP, because of data store requirements, this is not practical at this time.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is re-newing an expired token. We don't support that. And also don't have plans to do that.

You could set the expiration time to a value that works for you - and then force re-login after that.

1 MB tokens are not a good idea - you either need to roundtrip that, or create session affinity. Tokens are meant to describe user identity, not to dump every possible value into them.

Why doesn't the RP load the authZ rules from the IdP via a service call?

Comment: The plan, presently, would be to issue ~12 hr expiration tokens from the auth realm and then use the auth realm tokens as authentication to the other realms. It is understood that IdP won't allow renewal of the auth realm token.

Regarding having "the RP load the authZ rules from IdP via service call:" this is something I am not familiar with. Could you provide a link to a tutorial or sample implementation, please?

Comment: Instead of transmitting your authZ rules via the token. Create a webservice where the RP can retrieve them.

Comment: To go deeper into what Dominick is getting at, the claims in your issued token should be a set of properties about the principal: name, title, rank, department, project they work on, etc. Claims are not permissions and your STS should not be making authorization decisions on behalf of the RP who is consuming the token. It should be the RP who runs a principal's set of claims through a policy (rules set) in order to make authorization decisions. There's a difference between theory and practice, but that is what claims are in theory at least.