# STs trusting other STS token

Tags: ws-federation, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm using thinktecture idserver 3 to auth some APIs, (STS A), now I would like to have a new STS (STS B) in a different network (probably a DMZ) and make tokens from STS B work in STS A.

The APIs uses STS A for auth but I would like to call the API with tokens from STS B.

From what I have searched, fond this
[Authenticate to STS by Issued Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087386/authenticate-to-sts-by-issued-token)
it states it's possible by setting WsTrust but dont really have details and dont even know if its possible

Has anyone have done this and know the details or at least point in the right direction ?

If its like the url above, would it mean enabling ws federation on both STS and then make one trust the other one?

Note that in theory STS B wont have conectivity to STS A, maybe STS A can communicate with STS B if required. So I cant setup STS A as an identity provider to STS B

Comment: Sounds like you want to allow access to the API by clients authenticated from either Identity Provider A or B. So important missing details are:1) what technology is the API implemented in? 2) what federated auth protocol are you already using for controlling access to the API (you mention WS-trust but I think that's just in the article you reference). 3) Can you just configure the API auth middleware with 2 IDPs?

Comment: Yes indeed that is what I ended up doing setup the API auth to accept both IDPs. API is .net webapi using JWT tokens from STS. Still it would be good to know how to setup trust between two STS for future reference in case say internal APIs couldnt access external STS, but for my use case, accepting both STS works